# Flickering/blinking of JDialog as notification

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, notifications, jdialog

I'm using a JDialog to display notifications in bottom right corner of my application. I'm displaying up to 4 notifications and the most recent on is on top. Notifications are showing according to content from server, so there could be just 1 notification or 3, maximum 4. That causes resizing of JDialog and resizing causes to change location of JDialog in order to be always aligned in bottom right corner. Changing location on every new notification income causes flickering of JDialog.

Below is code which i call everytime when new notification come:

```
private void updateDialog()
{

    Point p = frame.getLocationOnScreen();
    p.x += frame.getWidth()-getWidth()-5;
    p.y += frame.getHeight()-getHeight()-25;

    setLocation(p); 
    pack();
    repaint();
}
```

Did anybody have simliar problem? How did you solve it? Any other advice on what should i try to do?

Comment: Post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) and we may find your problem. But it should not flicker.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet SSCCE is today down, for me :-), I sent request to his majesty about that :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I just tried it again and it is OK.  Still down for you? BTW - *"his majesty"*?  No, just "He-man, master of the universe" will be fine. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson something wrong happens, without changes (including Swing JComponents, rest of tutorials works for me), maybe our squid proxy, ....... hehehe, well, right, without comments about your .... :-)

Answer (score 3):

- contraproductive is code line with repaint(), remove that,
- if isn't there another code lines inside void updateDialog(), then better would be, otherwise pack() should be wrapped into invokeLater();

code

```
private void updateDialog() {
    setVisible(false);
    Point p = frame.getLocationOnScreen();
    p.x += frame.getWidth() - getWidth() - 5;
    p.y += frame.getHeight() - getHeight() - 25;
    setLocation(p);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pack();
            //repaint(); // useless remove this codeline
            setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just wondering why you hide and then show the dialog and if the `pack()` call shouldn't  occur before the setLocation so that the getWidth() and getHeight() will return the updated values set by the LayoutManager?

Comment: everything about `Initial Thread` is for me about two methods `pack` and `setVisible`, btw I have got very good experiences with a.m. codes lines,  by assuming that OP `a)` re_use JDialog or `b)` create a new on runtime

Comment: @Guillaume Polet now I see that you don't know how to use URL in the comments click to the help(left bottom under comment window), then copy '"[link](http://example.com)"', here is displayed chars '"[link]"' and here url '"(http://example.com)"'

Comment: Ok, my bad, but I found that the links just work by pasting the URL. I am too lazy to write the complete stuff. Is it really poorly considered to not use proper links in comments?

Comment: sorry, I guess I woke up too tired this morning. Will bang my head against the wall 3 times for that